# how I open website after loading icon which is gif image

Tags: asp.net

i am developing website which opens directly in a browser but i want that it should open after gif image which rotates in circle and i use it but gif image rotates continuously but website does not open

my code is as

```
<body class="home blog">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table class="doc-loader">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="ajax-document-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

css code for doc-loader is as

```
.doc-loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;  
    }

.doc-loader td {   
     background-color: #1e1e1e;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and hide the image when the page finishes loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.doc-loader').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make your home page run under update progress and use the following code.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" DisplayAfter="0" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="div1" align="center" runat="server" class="page_loader" style="width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div id="Progress">
            <img src="clock.gif" id="img1" runat="server" alt="Loading..." style="position: absolute;
                left: 45%; top: 40%; visibility: visible; height: 100px; z-index: 99999;" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, have added a youtube video so that some time is taken for page to load and the loader is visible.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table class="doc-loader">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://sierrafire.cr.usgs.gov/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h2>Other content</h2>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/rYXBbREtRB0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</form>
```

and some jquery to hide loader on page load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.doc-loader').hide();
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/4u8rZ/1/